# How to do Button click and list view item click in customize list view in android

Tags: android

I have 4 items in my list view in these 3 are text view and one is button in my case i have to open 2 new activities from a single list

1st from on button click
2nd from on list view item click

but when i add the button in list view list click is not working, also i am not able to handle the click of button.

I am using BaseAdapter class to set the data in list view.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: try using image instead of button in a list view. and catch its click event to open a new activity.

Comment: Since Button is facusable element thats why you have to handle click events on your self that onItemclick will not work accroding my experience.Using Image will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Or you can just set to you button

```
android:focusable="false"
```

In this case you ListView will fire onItemClick action to listener, and the Button will also work when it clicked.

Comment: when button is clicked, will it fire both the events one for the button click and other for list view clicked?

Comment: No, just button. ListView clicked not fired.

Answer (score 13):

The previous answers to this didn't worked for me.

Add to your row's root layot android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants", this really does the trick, the buttons keep working and the list keeps firing the event.